# Searching through a JSON document with many objects for a specific element in each object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I'm doing a project where I want to measure the input response of a drone. The API we're using has a function to save the flight metadata to a JSON file, and every "ping" of data is saved as its own JSON object. I want to print certain elements in these objects to their own document so I can plot them in MatLab, but I can't figure out how to do that besides to manually go through and copy-paste about 2500 pieces of data.

Fair warning, I just started learning Python and JSON and pretty much everything else relating to programming this summer, so I'm VERY new to all of this. I would use something like ObjectPath or JSONpath to search for specific elements within the JSON object, but the Python scripts I'm using saves many, many JSON objects to one .json file, and I haven't been able to find a tool that is able to read it, because there are no top-level objects, so at the end of the first JSON object, all the viewers and readers I've used expect EOF and don't work. Again, I'd really like to avoid having to manually create a top-level object for 850+ JSON objects.

So if I have

```
["Object", {"element1": {"w": 1, "x": 2, "y": 3, "z": 4}, "element2": {}, "element3": 0}]
```

that's one piece of flight metadata and is a valid JSON object. Then say I have multiple, or

```
["Object", {"element1": {"w": 1, "x": 2, "y": 3, "z": 4}, "element2": {}, "element3": 0}]
["Object", {"element1": {"w": 9, "x": 8, "y": 7, "z": 6}, "element2": {}, "element3": -1}]
["Object", {"element1": {"w": 2.5, "x": 5, "y": 7.5, "z": 10}, "element2": {}, "element3": 1}]
```

How would I get a file full of these to print all "element1" elements so that I wouldn't have to manually extract all the data? The formatting of the flight metadata output file (which I can't change) is exactly as I've shown above, with one JSON object surrounded by square brackets, then a paragraph break, then another JSON object.

This probably proves my newness at this, but I did try to make all of these objects into elements of one very large object at the start of the file to see if it liked that better, such as:

```
{
"Everything":
    ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 1, "x": 2, "y": 3, "z": 4}, "element2": {}, "element3": 0}]
    ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 9, "x": 8, "y": 7, "z": 6}, "element2": {}, "element3": -1}]
    ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 2.5, "x": 5, "y": 7.5, "z": 10}, "element2": {}, "element3": 1}]
}
```

but of course that didn't work at all.

As I said, every reader I try to use on this massive .json file tells me it expects EOF at the end of the first object. This is probably an overly detailed question for a very simple answer, and if so I apologize. Just to be clear, the drone API is Python based and I'm running on an Ubuntu 18.04 system. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: So the examples I gave were apparently a little too simplified from the actual data, as the first proposed solution worked for the example data but not for my actual data. At the risk of being too detailed, I'll give two of the JSON objects that I'm working with as a better example.

```
["VMetaFrameType.V3", {"drone_quat": {"w": 0.56494140625, "x": 0.0079345703125, "y": -0.0142822265625, "z": -0.82489013671875}, "location": {}, "ground_distance": 0.935791015625, "speed": {"north": 0, "east": 0, "down": 0}, "air_speed": -1, "frame_base_quat": {"w": 0.48394775390625, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -0.87506103515625}, "frame_quat": {"w": 0.48394775390625, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -0.87506103515625}, "exposure_time": 9.98828125, "gain": 343, "awb_r_gain": 1.9345703125, "awb_b_gain": 1.8310546875, "picture_hfov": 69, "picture_vfov": 42.26953125, "link_goodput": 16506, "link_quality": 5, "wifi_rssi": -59, "battery_percentage": 48, "animation": 0, "state": "HOVERING", "mode": "MANUAL", "frame_timestamp": 252549063, "automation": {"framing_target": {}, "flight_destination": {}, "followme_enabled": 0, "lookatme_enabled": 0, "angle_locked": 0, "animation": "NONE"}}]
["VMetaFrameType.V3", {"drone_quat": {"w": 0.56524658203125, "x": 0.007568359375, "y": -0.01458740234375, "z": -0.82470703125}, "location": {}, "ground_distance": 0.9384765625, "speed": {"north": 0, "east": 0, "down": 0}, "air_speed": -1, "frame_base_quat": {"w": 0.48394775390625, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -0.87506103515625}, "frame_quat": {"w": 0.48394775390625, "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": -0.87506103515625}, "exposure_time": 9.98828125, "gain": 343, "awb_r_gain": 1.9345703125, "awb_b_gain": 1.8310546875, "picture_hfov": 69, "picture_vfov": 42.26953125, "link_goodput": 16506, "link_quality": 5, "wifi_rssi": -59, "battery_percentage": 48, "animation": 0, "state": "HOVERING", "mode": "MANUAL", "frame_timestamp": 252582418, "automation": {"framing_target": {}, "flight_destination": {}, "followme_enabled": 0, "lookatme_enabled": 0, "angle_locked": 0, "animation": "NONE"}}]
```

That formatting is exact. After each "NONE"}}] there is a paragraph break.

Comment: After some messing around with specific syntax, I did get it to recognize all 850+ individual objects as elements in a much larger object. It required me to remove the square brackets on either end of every object and separate them all with commas, and then put brackets at either end of the very large object.

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully address your needs, but the problem with your final example is that the json isn't valid.

If you want one key "everything" to contain a list of lists, then you need to wrap your lists in brackets, with commas separating them.

```
{
"Everything": [
               ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 1, "x": 2, "y": 3, "z": 4}, "element2": {}, "element3": 0}],
               ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 9, "x": 8, "y": 7, "z": 6}, "element2": {}, "element3": -1}],
               ["Object", {"element1": {"w": 2.5, "x": 5, "y": 7.5, "z": 10}, "element2": {}, "element3": 1}]
              ]
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional syntax didn't work. It still kept telling me it expected EOF.

Comment: The JSON snippet above should not produce any errors. Can you update your question with full code and traceback?